# BizTalk publish net.tcp WCF service

Tags: wcf, biztalk

Is anybody familiar with setting up WCF-nettcp adapters for BTS?

When I create a WCF-netTcp adapter for a Receive location, I am unsure how/when BTS will open up port 808 to listen on the address URI specified. It appears to only happen if I restart the entire BizTalk application. If it closes for some reason, I do not see any way of reconfiguring and reopening the port.

Furthermore, since that is only the net.tcp binding, there is no mex endpoint exposed. I believe client applications that wish to use that exposed WCF service needs mex metadata initially. Accessing that endpoint direct from a Visual Studio project would just yield

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://biztalkserver/PostReceiveLocation_TCP/PostReceiveService.svc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://biztalkserver/PostReceiveLocation_TCP/PostReceiveService.svc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Cannot tell for such how to properly expose a mex endpoint to the service. the BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard is confusing me; I cannot get it to reference the WCF adapter/Receive location I setup. I find no document that teaches what one ought to do for netTcp services; it is all about Http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, it took the [walkthrough about publshing Net-Msmq WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259950.aspx) to nudge me thinking how the WCF Service Publishing Wizard really works.

The issue is this: When I manually created the WCF-netTcp Receive location, it has its endpoint URI e.g. net.tcp://biztalkserver/PostReceiveLocation_TCP/PostReceiveService.svc. When selecting the option to publish just an mex endpoint in the WCF Service Publishing Wizard, it will eventually ask for the WCF Service Location, which i confused to be the actual service location. Since it would accept nothing but Http URLs, it appeared to only support Http-based WCF endpoints.

But for that textbox, one is supposed to place the Http URL that for *just the mex endpoint*, not the actual net.tcp WCF endpoint. That is the location in IIS where the wizard will create the necessary meta-data files. Once finished, that location, hosting a mex endpoint will inform clients of the real service located at the net.tcp endpoint.